# What is the purpose of the single underscore variable in Python?

Tags: python, syntax, pyqt, underscore.js

What does this line mean in python code exactly this (,_)? this is a line to connect my PyQt UI with my python script

```
FROM_CLASS, _ = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "car_Proj.ui"))
```

without this ,_ i got this error

> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from the [source code](https://gist.github.com/mstuttgart/bc246b25b8e0f7edd743), `loadUiType` returns two objects: `form_class` and  `base_class`. From your code, it seems you aren't interested in the `base_class`, so you name it `_`, which is a convention for "unimportant" variables. Alternatively, you could use:

```
FROM_CLASS = loadUiType(path.join(path.dirname(__file__), "car_Proj.ui"))[0]
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893946/6671176) for more information on the `_` conventions in python

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple: when `loadUiType` returns two values but you want to store only one for later use, you can assign one to the dummy variable `_`. It also works with more than just two return values (`_, my_var, _, _, _ = returns_five_values()`).